# Why does insert into a table from a file spawn multiple mappers but insert into a file from another file doesn't?

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive

When I insert data into a table from a file, one of whose attributes was date, only 1 mapper was spawned.

But when I insert from this new table into another table, this time converting the date attribute into a year, month, and day attribute, multiple mappers were spawned. What is the reason for this?

Comment: Please paste your code for more information.

Answer (score 0):

Number of mappers depends on the input split.

It seems that your file job has a single file as an input and you use something like FileInputFormat in configuration. With this settings hadoop will create a single mapper to process input.

Table input jobs in hadoop usually create 1 mapper per table region. It seems that your table has several regions because of HBase region auto-split feature. That's why you have several mappers.